# The correct way to ask if delivery to our home is available?

Tags: conversations

I'm trying to ask a company if they can make a business trip to my home. What would be the correct phrase on the phone?

> 新宿に自宅で出張が可能ですか？
>   新宿まで自宅を出張が可能ですか？
>   新宿まで自宅の出張ができますか？

Which would be more natural?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: subject has "delivery" while Q body mentions "business trip".  which is it?

Comment: Business trip. Thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something but how can you do a business trip to someone's home? AFAIK usually it means visiting a partner company etc. Do you have a home office or something?

Comment: also you might want to edit the subject

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, delivery and business trip can mean the same thing if we're talking about a certain type of business...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid none of the options sound grammatic, but this should be ok:

> 新宿の自宅まで出張できますか？

Or more clearly:

> 新宿にある私の自宅まで、出張していただけますか？